# Unexpected token else when using if, else if and else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an error in the code below. Tried all combinations of if and elseif but can't get it to work.

The error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else

```
if(disableAd == 0 && disableWeather == 0) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "depart18_ad_P.php";
    }, RefreshRate);
} elseif(disableWeather == 0) {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "weather.php";
    }, RefreshRate);
} else {
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "depart18_P.php";
        }, RefreshRate);
}
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: There is a space between `else` and `if` - `else if` it is

Comment: `elseif` has to be `else if` in Javascript.

Comment: Hi all, tried putting a spce in as else if, but I still get the same error.

Comment: it's called syntax error. `elseif` needs to be `else if`

Comment: @DCJones No you don't http://jsfiddle.net/bg7azw4y/. Also note that the logic make more sense like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bg7azw4y/3/

Comment: If you still haven't got this to work, then comment out everything inside `{}` so you only have `if {} else if {} else {}` - or try the same in a new snippet or jsfiddle with no other code to confuse the issue.

Comment: If you still get the error, then it's with code that you haven't presented here, hence the suggestion to try with a blank jsfiddle to prove *to you* that this is not where your problem lies.  Rory has taken the time to do this for you.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hi and many thanks for looking at this. Your code works perfectly. I just need to compare yours and mine to get my head around why mine did not work. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your `if-else` as already pointed out in the comments. However, you can simplify your code using ternary operator.

```
var _href = (disableAd == 0 && disableWeather == 0) 
              ? 'depart18_ad_P.php' 
              : ((disableWeather == 0) 
                  ? 'weather.php' 
                  : 'depart18_P.php');
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = _href;
}, RefreshRate);
```

Comment: Either add the code as plain code (not runnable) or declare undefined variables as ReferenceError is coming on running your code.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal it seems like I did not removed that while formatting the code in the editor. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: "Simplify". Props to you if you can still figure out at a glance what your first line does when you revisit that code.

Comment: If OP can't manage a few brackets around if/else then perhaps a *nested* ternary solution is not the best approach?

Comment: Reformatted to make it clearer (IMO) than a single line

Comment: @freedomn-m i agree with that comment and appreciate the edit

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal - It can be further simplified to `var _href = disableWeather == 0 ? disableAd == 0 ? 'depart18_ad_P.php' : 'weather.php' : 'depart18_P.php';`